# Verbosity of unit testing in untyped languages

Tags: unit-testing

I'm asking myself how verbose I should be when unit testing projects written in untyped languages like `Javascript`.

Let's take an example for a strongly typed language (`C#`)

```
public bool Foo(MyClass myClass) { /* ... */ }
```

As `C#` is strongly typed I can be sure that `myClass` is either `null` or an actual instance of `MyClass` (or any instance of a subclass if possible) so my testable values are just these.

Now let's port this method to `Javascript`:

```
function foo(data) { /* ... */ }
```

Now I can't be sure what type `data` is of as it could be anything.
Inside `foo` I can check which type `data` has but to ensure that the function works even with invalid types I would have to test all possible types in my unit tests which produces a lot of extra code.

This topic really bothers me especially in untyped languages where I cannot determine the actual type just by looking at the code. On the one hand I don't want to write a whole lot of code to test every possible type. On the other hand I feel like I'm missing something if I test just the types I'm expecting.

Are there any general recommendations or best practices for this problem?

Comment: "*ensure that the function works even with invalid types*" you mean you would write tests that check if it properly rejects invalid types?

Comment: @Torben: Can you illustrate a scenario where the potential exists for an invalid type?  Unit tests are meant to test for known scenarios, not unknown ones, and if your code otherwise produces the correct output...

Comment: One way you could solve the problem is use ES6 or Typescript.

Comment: [Types Don't Substitute for Tests](http://literateprogrammer.blogspot.com/2014/10/types-dont-substitute-for-tests.html)

Comment: For complex data objects, I prefer sticking to ordinary objects rather than classes and validating against a schema. But I put the validation inside the actual function, so the tests don't have to explicitly bring it up (except of course for one that checks it fails on bad data).

Comment: @RobertHarvey That blog post is interesting, but I don't agree 100% with. Types definitely substitute for *some* tests (of course, not all tests).

Comment: That's what I'm asking.  *What tests do they substitute for?"*

Comment: @RobertHarvey An advanced type system that allows you to specify non-empy lists would get rid of the test scenario "what happens to this function when it receives an empty list". A type system that allows you to specify union types A | B | C means you don't have to consider any other case in your tests. Of course, like the author of the blog you linked to says, maybe when you're using untyped languages you simply give those guarantees up and don't even want to test for them. But in my experience, that's unwise :)

Comment: Relevant: [Unit testing isn't enough. You need static typing too.](http://evanfarrer.blogspot.com/2012/06/unit-testing-isnt-enough-you-need.html)

Comment: @AndresF., are there languages which have the empty lists as a distinct type?

Comment: @null: Yes I do at least kind of. If I expect a function to get a string passed to as a parameter I would also check that this function does handle invalid parameters correctly. Incorrect parameters could only be incorrect values but I think it's legit to test for incorrect types too (if possible like in JS).

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Totally forgot Typescript, would be an option to think of.

Comment: @WinstonEwert Mainstream languages? I don't know. But I'm pretty sure non-empty lists can be codified [using dependent types](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9374698/147346).

Comment: @AndresF. There are mainstream languages today that support dependent typing. A useful subset can be done in Haskell. I understand that R supports dependent types, also.

Comment: @WinstonEwert It's possible to track the emptiness of an immutable list after the run-time check to see if it's empty. Create a new type for empty lists that takes a regular (unknown whether it's empty or not) list in its constructor; then it either returns an instance of your new empty list type, or fails (returns an empty optional, throws an exception, whatever). As a result if you manage to obtain an instance of the new type you know that the list it wraps is, in fact, empty.

Comment: @Doval, sure, but what operations are allowed on these list types? When I do operations on a list that return a list, what type of lists are returned? Depending on how that is built, it could either help find bugs or just constantly get in my way.

Comment: @WinstonEwert It has no operations. The type is just a wrapper that holds a list. Its purpose is to serve as proof of the list's emptiness - you couldn't have possibly constructed an instance of it unless it wrapped an empty list. The usefulness of this is that you can now define functions that take this type as an argument and you're guaranteed that they can only be called with empty lists. When you try to create an instance of the new type, your code will fork - either the list is empty and you succeed, or it's not and you get nothing back (or an exception) (cont'd...)

Comment: @WinstonEwert ... In the branch where creation of the type succeeds, you have proof of the list's emptiness. This is better than just producing a boolean value, because you can still end up accidentally passing a non-empty list to a method that expects an empty list (or vice-versa).

Comment: On a minor note, it would be kinda silly to have a function that only takes the empty list as an argument. The interesting case is a function that only takes a non-empty list.

Comment: @Dorval, so your approach doesn't do what I'd primarily find useful, tell me when I'm doing something illegal with an empty list. What it does do, is tell me when I've claimed something is an non-empty list, but isn't. I don't know, but it doesn't seem particular useful to me.

Comment: @WinstonEwert It protects you in similar ways as Optional - you can't accidentally use the list because you explicitly have to unwrap it. It's true functions that require an empty list are silly, but the technique is easily generalized to anything you would want to check in an `if` before using the value (i.e. this is a non-negative number, this list contains some value of interest, whatever). The only limitation is that it only works with immutable objects (you can't provide static guarantees about facts that can change at runtime.)

Comment: @Doval, what do you mean accidentally use the list? Do you mean start doing operations on an list I know is empty? Ok, but as noted you'd never take an argument that could only be an empty list, so its kinda pointless. And going on to a discussion of other types is beside the point I was raising around the practicality of types for empty/non-empty lists.

Answer (score 4):

Some languages allow you to ensure more conditions at compile time than others.  For those condition expressable (and thus ensurable) at compile time, you don't have to test for.

Those conditions that cannot be expressed by the language, or somehow cannot be expressed at compile time, ought to be tested.  You will need to test *both* on the callers' side and callees' side -- that the callers provide valid and don't provide invalid input (to the callees), and that the callees appropriately reject invalid input while accepting valid input (and vise versa for return values).

There is variation among languages, for example, using nullable (or sometimes optional), some languages can move null checking into the compile time ensured set.

It is a matter of degree where and how much type systems eliminate checking. Many conditions cannot be expressed at compile time in most of today's languages (e.g. a list is not empty).

Further, some strongly typed languages make certain weakenings, such as a typedef or type alias that considers two types as equivalent when perhaps they ought to be distinct.

Many popular statically typed languages allow casting to Object and then down casting later.  Such downcasting operations also forgo compile time checking, and thus are subject to increase testing requirements.

If you are working in a language with a weak type system, you certainly should look into a general purpose way to test for the presence of all required qualities (of parameters, return values, etc...) and rejection any disallowed qualities.

Type systems are good for what they do, but that being said, a type system will never be able to ensure all possible necessary conditions, and, that also varies by language (even among the strongly typed), and even among those, by the chosen programming style.

Answer (score 3):

> On the one hand I don't want to write a whole lot of code to test
>   every possible type. On the other hand I feel like I'm missing
>   something if I test just the types I'm expecting.

Honestly, you just need to get over it.

Coders working in dynamically typed languages don't generally worry about what happens when the incorrect types get passed into their function. They don't write extra code to check the types, and they don't write tests to verify what functions do when passed the wrong types. They write pretty much the same tests they would have written had they been working in a statically typed language.

At some level, what happens in a function passed the wrong argument types does not matter, as you won't pass those argument types in a working program. But, obviously, you will accidentally pass them in some cases. Here is the loss you take when you adopt dynamic typing, as it will take longer to identify the problem.

Whether or not this loss is acceptable is a hotly contested question. Advocates of dynamic typing argue that in practice, this kind of error is not overly common and easily detected and resolved. Thus it is an acceptable loss. Advocates of static typing argue that these kind of error is very common, often not easily detectable, and not always trivial to resolve. Thus is it not an acceptable loss.

However, the one thing you shouldn't do is try to program in a dynamically typed language as if it were a statically typed one. Don't try to get the same guarantees you had in a statically typed language. That will only lead to madness. You'll only succeed in making a crappy statically typed language out of a dynamically typed one.

Comment: I guess that is exactly my problem. I'm used to program in statically typed languages for years and I only switch to dynamically typed on occasion for specific tasks or to try something out.

Comment: @Torben you lose other things, too. Some JS libraries lead to code that's rather cryptic, wrapping every other line of code in *yet another closure* sometimes borders on obfuscation. IDEs generally don't keep up with the ever evolving libraries and often cannot provide much help in terms of code completion.

Comment: @TorbenJonas, I had the same reaction when I started working with dynamically typed languages. What I can say is that when you work with them extensively enough, you can begin to appreciate the flexibility of those languages. I'll also note that javascript is not a great example, as its got a lot of warts which have nothing to do with its dynamic typing.